# Exponential bound for very weak sunflowers?

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Call $r$ sets *diverse* if for every $0\le i\le r$ there is an element contained in exactly $i$ of them.
A family of sets is *r-diverse* if any $r$ of its members are diverse.

> Is there for every $r\ge 3$ a $C_r$ such that the size of any $k$-uniform $r$-diverse family is at most $C_r^k$?

This question is a special case of the sunflower conjecture and the [recent](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.05992) near-sunflower conjecture.

Update: I've realized that I don't even know why the family could grow exponentially in $k$ for $r=4$.

Comment: What is $C_r^k$?

Comment: The k-th power of a constant that depends on r.

Comment: Hm, for $r=2$ and $k>1$, if all sets have a common element and common non-element, they are arbitrary otherwise. And no bound at all.

Comment: @Fedor Indeed, the question makes little sense for $r=2$, just like for sunflowers.

Comment: What would be an example of, say, a 3-diverse family?

Comment: @მამუკა Good question! You could take a finite projective plane plus a universal point, contained in all the lines, but this only gives about $k^2$ sets.

Comment: Actually, it's not hard to make an exponential example: If you have a construction for $k-1$, then take two disjoint copies of it, F1 and F2, and add a new point x, such that you append x to every set from F1 and F2.

Comment: Actually, it's even simpler to take the root-to-leaf paths in a depth $k$ complete binary tree.

Comment: Pedantic comment, but the title says "weak sunflowers" when really you mean "weak sunflower-avoiding set."